# Comparing Error Two Columns in Calculated Field in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, if-statement, pivot-table, formula, calculated-field

I am trying to compare two columns in the calculated field in the pivot table as:

`=IF(Storage Unit < 'Sales Target'; "Low"; "Normal")`

[Insert Calculated Field (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL0EO.png)

Even if two columns are in the values field, it gives a value error.

Does anyone have any opinion about the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Calculated fields in pivot tables cannot return text values, only sums (please take a look at [this](https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html) site for more information). It's stated there that

> Sum is the only function available for a calculated field.

When it comes to a solution, I'd have another table with the pivot table's data imported to it, and with your `IF` formula to show "Low" or "Normal" sales.